# How to sort my array of char pointers

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

> for the program I have an array of char * named arr[] and I am trying to sort it alphabetically but having no luck doing so it does nothing when running the for loop at the end. I want to keep the offset[] with arr[] so because I need the char code and the offset for a file

```
typedef struct country {
    char code_name[4];
    char name[45];
    int population;
    float life_expect;
}country;

country data[240];

int main(void) {

    char *swap;
    int a=0,c=0,d=0,n=0;
    int cmp = 1;
```

> heres the arr[]

```
    char *arr[239];
    size_t offset[239];
    char *ptr;
    int i = 0;
    int temp;
    char buf[512];
    char *token;
    char buf_write[10000];
    size_t nbytes_written;  
    size_t t_nbytes;

    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("AllCountries.dat", "r");
    int wptr;
    wptr = open("BinaryAllCountries.dat", O_RDWR);
    FILE *rptr;
    rptr = fopen("BinaryAllCountries.dat", "r");    

    do {
        if (fgets(buf, 512 , fptr)){
            //printf("%s\n",buf);
            token = strtok(buf,",;");
            while (token != NULL){          
            token = strtok(NULL, ",;");
                if (temp == 0){
                strcpy(data[i].code_name, token);
                nbytes_written = write(wptr, token, strlen(token));
                t_nbytes = t_nbytes + nbytes_written;
                //printf("code_name: %s\n", data[i].code_name);
                }
                if (temp == 1){
                strcpy(data[i].name, token);
                cmp = strcmp(data[i].name, "Virgin Islands");
                nbytes_written = write(wptr, token, strlen(token));
                t_nbytes = t_nbytes + nbytes_written;
                //printf("name: %s\n", data[i].name);
                } 
                if (temp == 6){ 
                data[i].population = atoi(token);
                nbytes_written = write(wptr, token, strlen(token));
                t_nbytes = t_nbytes + nbytes_written;
                //printf("population: %i\n", data[i].population);
                }
                if (temp == 7){
                data[i].life_expect = atof(token);
                nbytes_written = write(wptr, token, strlen(token));
                t_nbytes = t_nbytes + nbytes_written;
                //printf("life expectancy: %f\n", data[i].life_expect);
                }
            temp = temp + 1;
            }
        arr[i] = data[i].code_name;
        offset[i] = t_nbytes;
/*
        printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
        printf("%lu\n", offset[i]);
*/      printf("--------\n");

        i = i + 1;
        temp = 0;
        }
    }while (!feof(fptr));
```

> here is where I tried to sort the array but nothing happens and the array stays the same

```
    for (c = 0 ; c < 10; c++){
            for (d = 0 ; d < 238; d++){
                if (arr[d] > arr[d+1]){
                swap     = arr[d];
                arr[d]   = arr[d+1];
                arr[d+1] = swap;
                }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i <239; i++){
        printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
    }
```

> here is what some of the output looks like from the arr[] as you can see it doesn't get sorted

DZA
AGO
BEN
BWA
IOT
BFA
BDI
CMR
CPV
CAF
TCD
COM
COG
COD
CIV
DJI
EGY
GNQ
ERI
ETH
GAB
GMB
GHA
GIN
GNB
KEN
LSO
LBR
LBY
MDG
MWI
MLI
MRT

Comment: What's wrong with `qsort()`

Comment: i want to keep the offset[] array associated with the char arr[] as i need them for a file

Comment: then define a struct with a `char *` and a `size_t` (or `off_t`, if it is a file offset) members, use an array of such structs, and sort it with `qsort()` and your own comparison function. The [man 3 bsearch](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bsearch.3.html) man page has an example of qsorting an array of structs.

Comment: so i can just add a size_t to my stuct and i can then qsort?

Answer (score 2):

> heres what i did and that allowed me to sort the struct based on the code_name field

```
static int
compmi(const void *m1, const void *m2)
       {
           struct country *mi1 = (struct country *) m1;
           struct country *mi2 = (struct country *) m2;
           return strcmp(mi1->code_name, mi2->code_name);
       }


  typedef struct country {
        char code_name[4];
        char name[45];
        int population;
        float life_expect;
        size_t offset;
    }country;

qsort(data, sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]),sizeof(struct country),compmi);
```

Comment: What is `compmi`?

Comment: oh sorry forgot that will put it in now